# Capture string in between

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I capture data in between a series of strings?

I have the following data in a column:
Basically, remove all before "INCIDENT TYPE:" and after "External ALARM ID:"
"INCIDENT TYPE:" has no specific number of characters.

```
HOSTNAME: sample.com INCIDENT TYPE: SampleSiteUpDown SOURCED FROM External External ALARM ID: 57536
```

And I only want to display the incident type value

```
Incident Type
SampleSiteUpDown SOURCED FROM External
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your messages have the fixed format of:

```
HOSTNAME: ... INCIDENT TYPE: ... ALARM ID:
```

we can use the base string functions here:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(msg,
              INSTR(msg, 'INCIDENT TYPE:') + 15,
              INSTR(msg, 'ALARM ID:') -
                  INSTR(msg, 'INCIDENT TYPE:') - 16) AS incident
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1abd1b0030ec50f65688d85cfa7cb873)

Comment: External alarm id has no specific number of character so i cannot use 15 or 16.

Comment: @pootoy The 15 is the length of `INCIDENT TYPE:` plus one space.  If you don't have a fixed structure message, my answer won't work.  Otherwise, it should work.

Comment: Is it possible to trim it instead of counting the character? Sorry, I am relly new to SQL. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`REGEXP_ SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099) queries, using something like

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(msg, 'INCIDENT TYPE: (.* SOURCED FROM External)', 1, 1,'', 1) FROM ...`

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b65f0284a6375d72a65a585a8180a950)

It's a little more concise and a little more flexible than the other solutions, I think.

Comment: ... and possibly a little (or a little bit more) slower than other solutions. Regular expressions are pretty, but slow on large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use good, old `substr` + `instr` combination:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'HOSTNAME: sample.com INCIDENT TYPE: SampleSiteUpDown SOURCED FROM External External ALARM ID: 57536'
  3     from dual
  4    )
  5  select substr(col, instr(col, 'INCIDENT TYPE:') + 15,
  6                     instr(col, 'External ALARM ID') - instr(col, 'INCIDENT TYPE:') - 16
  7               ) result
  8  from test;

RESULT
---------------------------------------
SampleSiteUpDown SOURCED FROM External

SQL>
```

Comment: You should be subtracting 16 from the third parameter to `SUBSTR` to remove the dangling space at the end.

Comment: External alarm id has no specific number of character.

Comment: It doesn't matter; what matters is length of "INCIDENT TYPE:"